# How can I pass the same id value between multiple views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Product List Page with a List of Products without main Navigations

[image]

On `View` link click from `Product List` Page above, I'm able to navigate to `Overview` page passing the selected product id correctly but when I click on Suppliers link from main navigation I would like to pass the same id value as overview page to Suppliers page because once I click view link everything is about the selected product. What is the best way to handle this? I tried to avoid using `TempData` or `Session`.

**_Navigation.cshtml look like as shown below**

```
<nav id="navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <ul id="nav_list" class="top-level-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/" class="first-level-link">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Supplier" asp-area="Supplier">Suppliers</a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Overview Action**

```
    [HttpGet]       
    public async Task<IActionResult> Overview(int id)
    {
        var productInfo = await _productService.GetProductDetailsByID(id);
        var productDTO = _mapper.Map<ProductOverview>(productInfo);         

        return View(productDTO);
    }
```

**Product Overview View Model**

```
 public class ProductOverview
 {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string ProductCode { get; set; }
   public string Type{ get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
 }
```

**Supplier Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int id)
{
var suppliers= await _suppliersService.GetAllSuppliers(3); //need help pass the selected productID
var suppliersDTO = _mapper.Map<Suppliers>(suppliers);         

return View(suppliersDTO);
}
```

**Supplier View Model**

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }        
 }
```

Comment: Since you show overview action you should show , overview view then. Or show navigation action, model and class pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Overview and Supplier views are treating the Navigation [as the layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0), or the Navigation is rendered as part of the layout, one option is to create a base or abstract model class that your outer layout ([and the navigation partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-data-from-partial-views), if it's separate) consume from.

For example, you might have a class like:

```
public abstract class LayoutBaseClass 
{
    public abstract int ProductId { get; }
}
```

Then, your ProductOverview and Supplier class can derive from this base class. The Layout view can take a dependency on the abstract/base class model, making those shared properties available to the layout so you can include them in the URL being generated in the nav, while the more granular views can continue to reference the more specific classes. You don't have to change anything in your controller when returning the view, in that case -- ASP .NET Core will propagate the model into both the layout and your view.

Comment: how can I make LayoutBaseClass > productId to take the selected productID passed from ProjectList Page I keep getting null exception error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` in `<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Supplier" asp-area="Supplier" asp-route-id="@Model.ProductId">Suppliers</a>`

Comment: If you're including the base class in the Layout, then all views that use it as a layout **must** return a model along side the View, even on a GET call and even if its in some "default" state, or you will run into a null reference. You can decide to conditionally render the nav item if that default state is present (i.e. productid == 0). The value will not automatically go from your project list links into to the model, it must be assigned to the model on each progressive call where a new model is returned (i.e. Overview GET returns it in its model, Supplier GET receives it and returns it)

Comment: Alternatively, you can have a different version of the Layout, one that expects no model (default state, doesn't pre-assume a selection) and one that does for Views where it is applicable.